# How can I break all lines or none in inline CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am designing an HTML email for a company.  I'm having a problem with the footer at the bottom.  Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

I love it!

When it's resized a lot, it looks like this:

[image]

Wonderful!  I DO want the footer to break onto 3 lines.

However, when I resize the window halfway, it looks like this:

[image]

What CSS code can I use to make the footer to either break ALL lines, or none?  It needs to ALWAYS look like either this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

But NEVER this:

[image]

and NEVER this:

[image]

I tried numerous combinations of `white-space: nowrap;` to no avail.  When ANY lines break, they need to ALL break at the same time.  Maybe this could be accomplished with a `<table>`?

Thank you for your help.  The CSS needs to be inline and without media queries.  JavaScript support for HTML email is very limited and non-reliable, therefore, I wish to do without it.

[A JSFIDDLE for editing can be found here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Godisgood/f1uuwexy/)

Comment: There may be some clever trick to do this, but in general you are depending on CSS to establish a complex constraint. That's just a little "beyond its pay grade."

Comment: normally this could be possible with `@media` queries however, support is limited: https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/media-query-support/

Comment: @haxxton agreed, he could do a `br` with a `display:none` media query but for the sake of email client support, the best thing would be `url<br>email<br>tel` to ensure everybody gets the format OP wants.

Comment: Just a suggestion, have different email templates based on the client's display resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The layout which you are trying is possible using media queries or javascript. but most of the email templates doesn't support both solutions.

So, as I see, you have two options:

- it will be better if you always keep the footer items independent to each row i.e add `br` tags between the `nav` tags.

#### or

- Create different email templates based on the resolution.

Personal suggestion: I would have gone with the first option.

Comment: Here is the fiddle to show the first option. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f1uuwexy/12/)

Answer (score -2):

```
<nav style="display:inline; white-space:nowrap;"> 
<a moz-do-not-send="true" style="text-decoration:none; word-break:break-all; color:white;" href="tel:1234567890">
(123) 456-7890
</a>
</nav>
```

Use

```
word-break:break-all;
```

**Jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/f1uuwexy/8/

Comment: This does both the things that it should never do. It should display on one line OR three lines, when two small for one line. Not two.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.  In the way I asked.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this using only html:

```
<div>
www.hazardmoving.com<br />
Patrickhazard@yahoo.com<br />
(123) 456 7890<br /></div>
```

You seem to try pushing css beyond its limits

If you feel comfortable including bootstrap you can try:

```
<link rel="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div style="width: 600px; margin: 60px auto; text-align: center;">
<div class="col-md-4">www.hazardmoving.com</div>
<div class="col-md-4">Patrickhazard@yahoo.com</div>
<div class="col-md-4">(123) 456 7890</div>
</div>
```

That should do the work. Check my pen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EajwXp

Comment: This will never allow it to be on one line. It will always be on three.

Comment: Try out the bootstrap part of it

Comment: This wont work in email clients :-\ Only very basic *inline* CSS has widespread support.

Comment: Bootstrap for email??

Comment: Am guessing you have something better to say

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.  In the way I asked.